# Sending an e-mail through MATLAB using Microsoft Outlook

Tags: matlab, email, outlook

I am using the function found at the following blog: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94446-can-i-send-e-mail-through-matlab-using-microsoft-outlook to send e-mails from my Outlook account from the MATLAB editor. It indeed works, and I can also include attachments or pictures etc.

My question is whether it is possible to send a result of another MATLAB function saved and run at the same directory. I tried calling the function like that :

```
sendolmail('email_address','Subject included',result of a function);
```

When I run this, a mistake is returned. It seems as if only strings or attachments from my computer can be sent through the function. Any ideas on how results of functions can be added and sent?

Comment: save the results to a file and/or image.

Comment: @matlabgui you forgot to say "D'uh!" :p

Answer (score 1):

No, it's all in HTML format, so you have to save the results to a file or convert the output to an HTML formatted output (could just be a string).